# Kotlin : Returning a default Generic Type for default interface function

Tags: generics, kotlin

I have a function defined in an interface. This function returns a Generic value. I would like that this value by default is a `CompletableFuture<Void>` as in many cases this `run()` function does nothing. I suppose the problem is the same in Java.

```
interface Command<out Payload, CommandResult> {

   fun run(): CompletableFuture<CommandResult>{
       return CompletableFuture.runAsync{}
   }
}
```

The compiler says there is a *Type Mismatch*

[image]

By default, we do nothing, so a `CompleteableFuture<Void>` return is good, and `runAsync()` does the job. In some case, the `run()` function will return a `CompleteableFuture<Car>` for example

Comment: I'm not following what this `run()` function is for since you pass `runAsync` an empty runnable. Do you intend to allow a runnable to be passed to this function? `runAsync` always returns `CompleteableFuture<Void>` so it doesn't make sense that you specify the return type as `CompletableFuture<CommandResult>`.

Comment: I would like that by default, we do nothing, so a `Void` return is good, and `runAsync()` does the job. In some case, the `run()` function will return a  `CompleteableFuture<Car>` for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve exactly what you are asking for, but you can get close by splitting it into two interfaces:

```
interface Command<out Payload, CommandResult> {
    fun run(): CompletableFuture<CommandResult>

    // other members
}

interface SimpleCommand<out Payload> : Command<Payload, Void> {
    override fun run() = CompletableFuture.runAsync{}
}
```

Comment: I was doing something close to this before, with a Command and a RunnableCommand. It works but there was some issue thought. Here I have a CommandProcessor that must be able to run both Command, without knowing if it's simple or not

Comment: So I can probably write two `process()` function : `process(runnableCommand)` and `process(simpleCommand)`

Comment: Because `SimpleCommand` extends `Command`, it can be passed anywhere a `Command<Something, Void>` can be passed, you don't need to do anything special for this.